# Django model_set.add() method doesn't work but no errors

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

So, I am working on a Django-based website (Django 3) and I am trying to use a file to add certain elements into the database. While reading the file and its data works smoothly, the script seems to stop abruptly on this line:

```
studentClass.student_set.add(student)
```

Right before that, I have lines like these being executed with no problem:

```
school = get_object_or_404(School, pk=form.cleaned_data['school'].pk)
        studentClass, created = StudentClass.objects.get_or_create(
            school=school,
            name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
            grade=form.cleaned_data['grade']
        )
.
.
.
print("\nSUCCESS!\n")
print("\nAttempting to add {} to {}".format(
                    student,
                    studentClass))
studentClass.student_set.add(student) <---- SUSPECTED CULPRIT!
print("SUCCESS!")
```

The output from the print statement to the console:

```
Attempting to add (<Student: 1 - Jessica>, False) to 1 - HenMei
```

EDIT: I did not see this the first time, but if it relates to the question and someone smart enough to know what that "False" in the string output above is, an explanation would be much appreciated.
The second print statement:

```
print("SUCCESS!")
```

is not executed, thus I am quite sure that

```
studentClass.student_set.add(student)
```

is the line that's causing some trouble. Since I am a beginner, I may very well be wrong.
EDIT: Just to make sure that the way I was doing things wasn't part of the problem, I also tried to rewrite the line above to:

```
student.studentClass.add(studentClass)
```

But the same thing happened; no output after that line either.

Models are defined as follows:

```
class StudentClass(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    grade = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['grade', 'name']

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.grade, self.name)

class Student(models.Model):
    studentClass = models.ManyToManyField(StudentClass)
    student_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, default='Female')

    class Meta:
        ordering = [F('student_number').asc(nulls_last=True)]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.student_number, self.first_name)
```

Last but not least, here's the last line that gets printed to console:

```
[16/Jun/2020 18:14:06] "POST /teachadmin/addStudentClass/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

Which doesn't tell me a whole lot, but I thought maybe you professionals out there might need it :P

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear - I have checked the database and confirmed that no additional Students are added by this script. The code just abruptly stops running.

Comment: That's strange. Where are you running your Django application? In some environments (like docker) printing isn't always shown right away due to buffering.

Comment: I am still running the project locally in my own environment. But since the objects I intend to add to the database aren't added properly, I'd say that it seems that whether it's printing or not isn't the real issue, but rather a temporary debugging toll that I use ;)

Comment: Should obviously be "debugging tool" ><

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of hours searching through the (wrong part of the) documentations for Django, I finally realized that I had not been doing any *tuple unpacking* on the following line:

```
student = Student.objects.get_or_create(
                    student_number=row.Index,
                    first_name=row.Name,
                    gender=row.Gender
                )
```

You might be confused and say "Umm.. I didn't see this?". That is perfectly normal - I was an idiot and thought "There can't possibly be a mistake in there."
This proved to be wrong as the statement:

```
studentClass.student_set.add(student)
```

tries to add the *tuple* instead of a Student-object.

Instead, I changed the line to simply do tuple unpacking on spot:

```
student, created = Student.objects.get_or_create(
                    student_number=row.Index,
                    first_name=row.Name,
                    gender=row.Gender
                )
```

And then finally go ahead and add the StudentClass to the Student object:

```
studentClass.student_set.add(student)
```

Sometimes it's funny how you assume someTHING is wrong with your code and you realize it was your own silly mistake all along... :P
Thanks to everyone who bothered checking in and thought about an answer :)